# How to format output using printf and a dialog box?

Tags: java

Using Java, how do I display the following "formatted code" in a dialog box?

```java
System.out.printf("%20s%20s%20.-5f%n%n", "Assessed Value:", "$", assessedValue); 
System.out.printf("%20s%20s%-5f%n%n", "Taxable Amount:", "$", taxedAmount);
System.out.printf("%20s%20s%-5f%n%n", "Tax Rate for $100.00:", "$", taxDollars);
System.out.printf("%20s%20s%-5f%n%n", "Property Tax:", "$", propertyTax);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `JOptionPane` class to show a message in the shape of a dialog.

That'd look like this:

```
public void showDialog() {
    String message = String.format("%20s%20s%20.-5f%n%n", "Assessed Value:", "$", assessedValue) + String.format("%20s%20s%-5f%n%n", "Taxable Amount:", "$", taxedAmount) + String.format("%20s%20s%-5f%n%n", "Tax Rate for $100.00:", "$", taxDollars) + String.format("%20s%20s%-5f%n%n", "Property Tax:", "$", propertyTax);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
}
```

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: I cannot understand why people are still recommending Java Swing instead of JavaFX...

Comment: JavaFX is a much better choice over Swing, I agree. But for the sake of simplicity I went with Swing here.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, these invocations are just using `String.format`, you can use that to generate your dialog box's content.